# How to have multiple Auth models in django

Tags: django, django-models, backend, django-auth-models

I have an application where I've two models both models have same fields

1. client
2. buyer

I'm using separate models because client can also signs up as a buyer using the same email and vice versa. I don't want to use single model for both client and buyer with some checks like is_buyer/is_client.
How do I achieve something like

```
class Client(AbstractUser):

    email = Field()
    password = Field()

class Buyer(AbstractUser):

    email = Field()
    password = Field()



AUTH_USER_MODEL=app.Client

AUTH_USER_MODEL=app.Buyer
```

Also I'm using simpleJWT library, so I can generate jwt when the client or buyer logins in.

Comment: Please *don't*. Use *one* user model, and perhaps add a `Client`/`Buyer` model with a `OneToOneField` to that user model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem if I use OneToOneField with buyer and client, can I have a same buyer record in the client model as well?

Comment: yes, both can point to the same user.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the User model and add a new field(Type) with two choices (client-buyer) and create two models (Client/Buyer) both of them OneToOne with the User model

when the user register, he will insert his type or you should find a way to know his type
then in the User model save his type
then save the other data in the next model (Client/Buyer) depending on the type